# How to make my Android App to act as Image Picker

Tags: android, image

I am developing an Android App which contains image collection with different type of Images.
I want my app to act as Image Picker.

For example when a user want to pick an Image to post on facebook or wahtsapp,chooser dialog gets opened with  gallery app option  and user select the image to post from gallery. What I want is my app should be listed  in Image Picker along with Gallery so that user can select image from my app.

Thanks

Comment: android do not have this type of control, Make it custom Picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple. You can register the `IntentFilter` for that corresponding **mime type** inside your `Activity` tag `AndoridManifest.xml` and your app will also be listed among the apps which can be used to pick images. Code:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```