# Android post image to Facebook comment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

This is a followup to my previous question: [Xamarin.Forms App return data to calling App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945166/xamarin-forms-app-return-data-to-calling-app)

That works perfectly and I can share images to anywhere, except to Facebook comments. When I click the camera on the content box the app can be selected, I can select the image, Set result and Finish are called, and the app closes and it sends data to Facebook, and then however I then get the error : The image could not be uploaded, try again?

I can't find any fundamental differences between posting to a status or a comment, so I'm guessing it's subtle. Any thoughts on how I can change my intent to post properly? [image: screenshot of error as shown in Facebook]

Adding for completeness:

```
Bitmap b = null;
string url;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.saleItems[i].ImageUrl))
{
    url = this.saleItems[i].ImageUrl;
}
else
{
    url = await FileHelper.GetLocalFilePathAsync(this.saleItems[i].Id);
}
//download
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
    if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
    {
        b = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    }
}
//set local path
var tempFilename = "test.png";
var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, tempFilename);
using (var os = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    b.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
}
b.Dispose();

var imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"file://{sdCardPath}/{tempFilename}");

var sharingIntent = new Intent();
sharingIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
sharingIntent.SetType("image/*");
sharingIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "some txt content");
sharingIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, imageUri);
sharingIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

//await SaleItemDataService.Instance.BuySaleItemAsync(this.saleItem);

SetResult(Result.Ok, sharingIntent);
Finish();
```

[image: This is a capture of the local stack when the intent is created, just before it does SetResult() and Finish()]

Comment: I know the path to the image is correct, I know it is being included in the intent, I have set permissions in the manifest for read and write external storage. This code works for Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Messenger and WhatsApp, it is only failing for Facebook comments. Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce but here are couple ideas: 1. Are you posting comment using the same user who created the original post? 2.If not, was the post created as public?

Comment: where can I post my comment to your post from the phone?

Comment: try to use another app on the phone to pick the picture. does that one goes through?

Comment: also try to upload photo of smaller size and may be different format

Comment: It's my Facebook post, and I commented, I but the post is friends only, I did a post with the same image to Facebook and twitter and that worked, size doesn't appear to be an issue, I can upload from gallery and Google photos to the same content thread. I will create a new public post and add a link here for testing, but I thanks :)

Comment: link for testing will definitely help

Comment: Test tweet, the same happens on tweet comments too, but the original photo was posted to Twitter from the app, https://mobile.twitter.com/iamshainefisher/status/888286371902668800

Comment: Facebook post https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1776863145937611&id=100008418289054 and is public :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149835/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-shaine-fisher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below:

```
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
        string imageUri = "file://" + requestedUri;
        sharingIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(imageUri));
```

Comment: As I said earlier, this is where I started with the original problem, in so happy I was right to start with, sadly I got lost trying to solve two slightly different problems at the same time. Thanks for your help, again.