# Xamarin.Forms. Is there any way to bring to front my app?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, applinks

I am developing an application with xamarin forms for android and ios. One of requeriments of the app is to react certain links from e-mail. I am able to react to these links and make the logic in the application but I need to bring the application to front.

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you in advance.
Sorry for my english.

Best regards.

Comment: Not sure but is this post perhaps helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945166/xamarin-forms-app-return-data-to-calling-app#comment76958292_44945166

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for a [custom URL scheme](https://xamarinhelp.com/uri-scheme/) and [deep linking](https://blog.xamarin.com/deep-link-content-with-xamarin-forms-url-navigation/).

With a custom URL scheme you can register for `yourapp://value1/value2`. Then whenever someone opens a link from e-mail or wherever which starts with `yourapp://` your app will be launched.

With deep linking you can even respond to 'normal' URL's. Like when you tap a Facebook profile link and your app gets opened, that is deep linking.

Comment: I want this but my app it´s not bring to front when I click in the link.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Forms for Android

After you get request in `MainActivity` or `SplashActivity` by URL Scheme

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     var data = Intent?.Data?.EncodedAuthority;
     if (data != null)
     {
        Finish();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
        IEnumerable<RunningTaskInfo> tasklist = am.GetRunningTasks(100);
        am.MoveTaskToFront(tasklist.First().Id, 0);
     }
     else
     {
        //....
     }
 }
```

You need to add

```
 "android.permission.REORDER_TASKS"
 "android.permission.GET_TASKS"
```

to AndroidManifest.xml

http://summarynote.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-how-to-bring-app-in-background.html